# Solr search query facet is returning only 100 results

Tags: solr, lucene, solrnet, faceted-search

I am calling solr search hosted on a different machine with a query. When I wrote a query, it returns `numFound=2405` matching docs. we have more than 10000 doc indexed. But the facet results that is being returned has only 100 count of ids that i am fetching as a facet fields.

---

My solr query is here (split for readability):

```
localhost:8983/solr/select/?
q="C"
&start=0&rows=10
&facet=on
&facet.field=currentEmployer
&facet.field=state
&facet.field=industry
&facet.field=education_university
&facet.field=workHistory_employer
&facet.field=id
&facet.mincount=1
```

---

why is this so? Please help me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Default value for [facet.limit](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.limitParameter) is 100
Add this request parameter to vary the number of facets returned.

A negative value means unlimited.

Comment: Adding a negative value for `facet.limit` doesn't return this facet.  Do you have any hint why would that be happening?

Comment: For me it works like a charm!!!! My problem was that on large results the low cout facet was not created. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

On your SOLR Server, edit the solrconfig.xml for the index you are using and add -1 as in snapshot below. SolrConfig.xml is found in the conf folder of your index. Find the requesthandler you are using, for e.g. "/select", -
[image]

Repeat this for each index that you want to update. Don't forget to restart your SOLR service. Once this was done, the facets started showing 100+ values.